# Viewport and CSS media query gets different width?

Tags: android, css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

I am having problem creating css media queries for smartphones, especially for Android devices such as Samsung Galaxy S3.

It seems like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` and CSS media query gets different data on device-width.

If I hold my Galaxy S3 in portrait mode its screen is 720 x 1280, and it seems like `content="width=device-width` from meta viewport is giving me the same width.

But if I look at same page in landscape mode it seems like `content="width=device-width` from meta viewport is still giving me 720 width while listening to a bigger sized media query, so to speak 1280.

This results in web pages loading with a somewhat zoomed view, probably since it thinks that 720 is max width.

Check screens:

**Galaxy S3 Portrait (Chrome)**

[image: Galaxy S3 Portrait]

**Galaxy S3 Landscape (Chrome)**

[image: Galaxy S3 Landscape]

Above was tested on Samsung Galaxy S3 with Chrome browser.

I have a similar problem, actually worse with the default Android browser called "Internet". There it seems to ignore all CSS media queries while still listening to viewport.

Check screen:

**Galaxy S3 Portrait (Default)**

[image: Default Android browser]

Comment: Have you tried checking out http://dpi.lv/ on the phone to see what dpi and width the viewport is pushing through?

Comment: i would appreciate an answer to this question, as it is inactive now

Answer (score 0):

Try using a inspector in the phone to play around with values and tags or post us a demo. It's hard to point out the exact problem without any code attached to your question.